# How to override clean method of a form generated by UpdateView?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is it possible to override a `clean method` of the form which is generated by **Class Based View** - `UpdateView`?

In `form`, I would override `clean` method to check, whether either first or second field is filled.

Form would be like:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        super(MyForm,self).clean()
        if bool(self.cleaned_data['first_field'])== bool(self.cleaned_data['first_field']):
            raise ValidationError("Please, fill the first or second field")
```

View:

```
class EditOrderView(UpdateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['language_from', 'language_to', 'level', 'short_description', 'notes',
              'first_field', 'second_field']
    template_name = 'auth/jobs/update-order.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, pk=self.kwargs["pk"], customer=self.request.user)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/my-orders/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.order = form.save()
        email.AdminNotifications.edited_order(self.order)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your view use your form by setting [`form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_class).

```
class EditOrderView(UpdateView):
    model = Job
    form_class = MyForm
    ...
```